# How to fix "Cannot login because Domain Not Available" Error in MS SBS 2003?

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, windows-sbs-2003

We have a server that is running 2003 SBS and is Active Directory Controller. When I try to login to the domain, I receive a message that the domain is not available. I have configured my user account and permissions accordingly. This is a problem that has been observed by others at our firm.
 It takes multiple attempts to finally have the server accept your login. Does anyone have any ideas about how to troubleshoot this? Should I look at the DNS or the AD Settings? Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take a look at the DNS settings first. As a first step, check the server and then check the clients. The server should be using itself only for DNS and the clients should be using the server only for DNS. Check that the server is registered in DNS with it's internal ip address.

Comment: Thanks, it was a combination of DNS and DHCP. The DHCP wasn't working, so the computers didn't know where the DNS server was.

Comment: I had the problem because SBS 2003 only allows 1 DHCP server on a network, and my router was acting as a DHCP server, so the DHCP service would not start on my SBS 2003 server.

Comment: Glad to hear that you got it worked out.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the only DNS servers your clients have are valid DNS servers for the domain (in this case, they'll probably only have 1 DNS server and it will be the SBS server)

Also, set this group policy to true:

> Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> System -> Logon -> Always wait for the network at computer startup and logon